# Use MacOS semantics for copy-paste

Tags: osx, copy-paste

I use Emacs on MacOS, installed by homebrew:

```
% ls -l /opt/homebrew/bin/emacs
lrwxr-xr-x  1 kwilliams  admin  44 Jan 31  2023 /opt/homebrew/bin/emacs@ -> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

In general the keyboard shortcuts are great, having things like `⌘S` and `⌘Q` and `⌘A` retain consistent behavior with typical Mac apps.  One area that's different is copy/paste behavior, though:

1. If I select a word (e.g. by double-clicking it) and do `⌘C` to copy (which seems to invoke `ns-copy-including-secondary`), the act of copying it also *deselects* the word.  A typical Mac application will leave it selected.
2. If I then select another word (double-click) and do `⌘V` (`yank`) to paste the copied word, Emacs seems to first *deselect* the selected word and *then* insert the copied text after it.

#1 isn't a super huge deal, but #2 makes it cumbersome to try to paste one copied string in multiple locations.

Is there a way to change the semantics of `yank` or bind `⌘V` to something else that acts closer to the Mac's typical paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to enable `delete-selection-mode`. From `C-h f delete-selection-mode RET`:

> When Delete Selection mode is enabled, typed text replaces the selection
> if the selection is active.  Otherwise, typed text is just inserted at
> point regardless of any selection.

You can find more information about it at the [Emacs wiki - DeleteSelectionMode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeleteSelectionMode), in the [Emacs FAQ - 5.9 How can I replace highlighted text with what I type?](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Replacing-highlighted-text.html)
, and [Emacs Manual - 12.3 Operating on the Region](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Using-Region.html)

Additional further reading you may be interested in are [13.6 CUA Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/CUA-Bindings.html)
 and [22.1 Mouse Commands for Editing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mouse-Commands.html)
 both from the [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/).

Comment: As an "emacs on macos" user, I generally stick with the defaults for such things, and enable `delete-selection-mode` as needed, which is rare.

Comment: Thanks!  I notice the docs talk about "typed text".  Is there a difference between typed text and yanked text in this context?  I wonder why it doesn't just refer to it as "inserted text".

Comment: No, there's no functional difference. I think the docs are just written from the perspective of keyboard interaction.